# Hibernate session.flush() --> How to update just dirty objects instead of everything?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, flush

I have got an application which uses Hibernate. The performance is very bad. If I change just one simple field, many many many objects are updated after the session.flush() is called.

I will show you some code snippets and log files, maybe you can spot the problems. I am not an Hibernate expert. I hope this is enough information to give me some hints? Probably, I have learn with a book to solve it by myself...

I think the problem is, that there is no lazy loading or that there is some wrong CASCADING? Most hbm.xml Files have "lazy=false". session.clear() is not called after flushing. But: If I also use session.clear(), then the first change works and will be persisted, but all following changes will not be persisted.

Here some snippets. I think this should be all important snippets? If you need more information, tell me. Thank you. Best regards, Kai Wähner

One mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="de.bea.plato.domain.Auftrag" table="AUFTRAG" lazy="false">
        <id column="OID" name="oid" length="25" type="java.lang.String" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="de.bea.plato.datastore.PlatoIdGenerator"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="projekt" column="ProjektOID"/>
        <many-to-one name="mitarbeiterLetzteAenderung" column="MitarbeiterOID"/>
        <property name="day" type="de.bea.plato.hibernate.TypeDay"/>
        <property name="dayLetzteAenderung" type="de.bea.plato.hibernate.TypeDay"/>
        <!-- fields of type String must not be set to "" -->
        <property name="bezeichnung" length="80" access="field"/>
        <property name="auftragsNummer" length="40" access="field"/>
        <property name="bestellNummer" length="40" access="field"/>
        <!-- fields of type String must not be set to "" -->
        <property name="bemerkung" length="1024" access="field"/>
        <property name="abrechenbarVon" type="de.bea.plato.hibernate.TypeDay"/>
        <property name="abrechenbarBis" type="de.bea.plato.hibernate.TypeDay"/>
        <property name="status" not-null="true"/>
        <many-to-one name="budget" column="BudgetOID"/>
        <property name="rechnungsempfaenger" length="255" access="field"/>
        <property name="zahlungsziel" length="1024" access="field"/>
        <many-to-one name="anschrift" column="AnschriftOID"/>
        <property name="projektFestPreis" not-null="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The configuration:

```
configuration = new Configuration();
try {
    configuration.addClass(Waehrung.class);
    configuration.addClass(BK.class);
    configuration.addClass(BetriebskalenderAusnahme.class);
    configuration.addClass(Mitarbeiter.class);
    configuration.addClass(TeilProjekt.class);
    configuration.addClass(Projekt.class);
    configuration.addClass(ProjektGruppe.class);
    configuration.addClass(StundenEntry.class);

    Properties properties = databaseInit.getHibernateProperties();
    configuration.setProperties(properties);
```

The method which is called by the Swing GUI after a field is changed:

```
   public void flush() throws PlatoDatastoreException {
        synchronized (syncObject) {
            if (session != null) {
                try {
                    session.flush();
                    session.connection().commit();
//                     session.clear();
                    updateLastUse();
                    log.info("Session flushed and connection committed.");
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error while flushing session", e);
                    throw new PlatoDatastoreException(e);
                }
            }
            else {
                log.info("Flush without an active session");
            }
        }
    }
```

Hibernate Properties:

```
name = companies/XYZ/hibernate_releaseTest2

hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.connection.pool_size= 10

# test system ----------------------------
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz:1521:abc
hibernate.connection.username=x
hibernate.connection.password=y

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
hibernate.query.substitutions= true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'
hibernate.statement_cache.size= 100
hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=1000

hibernate.c3p0.max_size=10
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=0
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=0
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=60
hibernate.c3p0.valdiate=false
```

Log file after one change to a field (as you see many many many things happen, but just one field is updated and shall be persisted):

```
31197 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - flushing session
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - processing flush-time cascades
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - done cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascading to saveOrUpdate: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener  - persistent instance of: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - ignoring persistent instance
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - object already associated with session: [de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt#ericjxxxxxxxtw8468gf00000]
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascading to saveOrUpdate: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener  - persistent instance of: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - ignoring persistent instance
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - object already associated with session: [de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt#normanzxxxxxfveje5pd00000]
31198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascading to saveOrUpdate: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener  - persistent instance of: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - ignoring persistent instance
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - object already associated with session: [de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt#normanzxxxxxysjbzgpe00000]
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascading to saveOrUpdate: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener  - persistent instance of: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - ignoring persistent instance
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - object already associated with session: [de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt#ericjxxxxxxx7ch468gf00000]
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascading to saveOrUpdate: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener  - persistent instance of: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - ignoring persistent instance
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - object already associated with session: [de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt#normanzxxxxx4mpke5pd00000]
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascading to saveOrUpdate: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener  - persistent instance of: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - ignoring persistent instance
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - object already associated with session: [de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt#normanzxxxxxhv7me5pd00000]
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascading to saveOrUpdate: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener  - persistent instance of: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - ignoring persistent instance
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - object already associated with session: [de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt#dominiknxxxxdyi3mkmf00000]
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascading to saveOrUpdate: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener  - persistent instance of: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - ignoring persistent instance
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - object already associated with session: [de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt#ericjxxxxxxxtnzjf5ff00000]
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascading to saveOrUpdate: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener  - persistent instance of: de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - ignoring persistent instance
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener  - object already associated with session: [de.bea.plato.domain.TeilProjekt#normanzxxxxxu40pe5pd00000]
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - done cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - done processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - done cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList
31199 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - done cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList
31200 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - done processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter
31200 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter
31200 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit
31200 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - done cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit


... a lot more of this ...


31467 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.StringType  - binding null to parameter: 5
31467 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BooleanType  - binding 'false' to parameter: 6
31467 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.DoubleType  - binding '5.0' to parameter: 7
31468 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.DateType  - binding '22 Dezember 2010' to parameter: 8
31468 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.CharacterType  - binding null to parameter: 9
31468 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.StringType  - binding null to parameter: 10
31468 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.DoubleType  - binding '0.0' to parameter: 11
31468 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.DoubleType  - binding '0.0' to parameter: 12
31468 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.DoubleType  - binding '0.0' to parameter: 13
31468 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.StringType  - binding 'userxxxxxxxxewshlhnd00300' to parameter: 14
31468 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.StringType  - binding 'userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00500' to parameter: 15
31468 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.StringType  - binding 'eur' to parameter: 16
31468 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.StringType  - binding 'userxxxxxxxx49zr90ig00000' to parameter: 17
31468 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher  - Adding to batch
31469 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher  - Executing batch size: 1
31521 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher  - success of batch update unknown: 0
31521 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher  - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
31521 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher  - closing statement
31522 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - post flush
31532 [Gui4j-Worker 0] INFO  de.bea.plato.datastore.PlatoDatastore  - Session flushed and connection committed.
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the graph of objects you are fetching into memory is too big since it takes more than 250ms to traverse it.

Therefore you definitely need to limit this graph with lazy loading. However, it's difficult to say how exactly you need to apply lazy loading without deep knowledge of your domain model and use cases. At least, try to remove `lazy = "false"` from `<class>` elements.

Comment: Thank you. Of course I have to analyse the whole code a lot more by myself. One more thought: I think I should use more sessions? In "Hibernate in Action" I read, that SessionFactory is expensive, but that you can use many Sessions. In this applications, the Persistence Context is very large I think... And am I right: Further changes after the first one are not persisted (if I use session.clear), because probably then all objects are in detached state - probably nowhere in the code the objects are reattached / merged again. And thus, after the second change is not persisted?

Comment: @Kai: Actually I/m not sure about the proper design of Swing application with Hibernate. Perhaps you need to detach the object after the are loaded and merge the changed object when you are going to save them. And yes, objects are in detached state after `session.clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem through some other forum topics: The following code is used in a constructor:

```
    projektGruppen = new ArrayList();
    projekte = new ArrayList();
    projekteWithInactive = new ArrayList();
    teilProjekte = new ArrayList();
    teilProjekteWithInactive = new ArrayList();
    kunden = new ArrayList();
    mitarbeiter = new ArrayList();
    mitarbeiterWithInactive = new ArrayList();
    betriebskalenderAusnahmen = new ArrayList();
    planEinheitSoll = new ArrayList();
    belegArten = new ArrayList();
    standorte = new ArrayList();
    betriebskalender = new ArrayList();
    waehrungen = new ArrayList();

    projektGruppenRO = Collections.unmodifiableList(projektGruppen);
    projekteRO = Collections.unmodifiableList(projekte);
    projekteROWithInactive = Collections.unmodifiableList(projekteWithInactive);
    teilProjekteRO = Collections.unmodifiableList(teilProjekte);
    teilProjekteROWithInactive = Collections.unmodifiableList(teilProjekteWithInactive);
    kundenRO = Collections.unmodifiableList(kunden);
    mitarbeiterRO = Collections.unmodifiableList(mitarbeiter);
    mitarbeiterROWithInactive = Collections.unmodifiableList(mitarbeiterWithInactive);
    betriebskalenderAusnahmenRO = Collections.unmodifiableList(betriebskalenderAusnahmen);
    planEinheitSollRO = Collections.unmodifiableList(planEinheitSoll);
    belegArtenRO = Collections.unmodifiableList(belegArten);
```

There are getters (e.g. getMitarbeiterSorted) which return the UnmodfiableList. So there exists one list for adding new data (e.g. mitarbeiter) and one unmodifiablelist (e.g. mitarbeiterRO) for getting the data.

In another forum topic I found this information:

> If I have a property of type Set in my
>   persistent class, I would like the
>   getter to return an unmodifiable list,
>   to be sure all changes are done
>   through special convenience methods of
>   adding and removing items. Hibernate
>   in Action suggested using
>   Collections.unmodifiableSet which I
>   thought sounded like a good idea. But
>   then I read that returning a different
>   collection from a getter, than the one
>   Hibernate called with the setter, will
>   cause Hibernate to update the
>   database.

The easiest way would be to remove the unmodifiablelists and just use one list for getter and setter?
Do you think I am on the right path to solve the problem?

I also add another part of the log file (you can see that after the ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE cascades, there is also a lot of stuff about "dirty checking collections" and "processing referenced collections"). I do not understand, why all this collection data is updated after each change of a single field :-(

```
3151 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: de.bea.plato.domain.BK.BKEntry
83151 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - done cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: de.bea.plato.domain.BK.BKEntry
83152 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Cascades  - done processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: de.bea.plato.domain.BK
83153 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - dirty checking collections
83178 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
83179 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxriq570ig00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxriq570ig00000] (initialized)
83180 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxriq570ig00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxriq570ig00000] (initialized)
83183 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00000] (initialized)
83185 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00000] (uninitialized)
83187 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00300], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00300] (initialized)
83188 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00300], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00300] (uninitialized)
83189 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00500], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00500] (initialized)
83191 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00500], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00500] (uninitialized)
83192 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00700], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00700] (initialized)
83194 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00700], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx8xshlhnd00700] (uninitialized)
83195 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00200], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00200] (initialized)
83197 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00200], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00200] (uninitialized)
83198 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#matthiasmxxxq0y3cs9f00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#matthiasmxxxq0y3cs9f00000] (initialized)
83200 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#matthiasmxxxq0y3cs9f00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#matthiasmxxxq0y3cs9f00000] (uninitialized)
83203 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxx7123secf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxx7123secf00000] (initialized)
83204 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxx7123secf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxx7123secf00000] (uninitialized)
83206 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxxwn49a1ef00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxxwn49a1ef00000] (initialized)
83207 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxxwn49a1ef00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxxwn49a1ef00000] (uninitialized)
83209 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxx1lyjstef00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxx1lyjstef00000] (initialized)
83210 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxx1lyjstef00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxx1lyjstef00000] (uninitialized)
83211 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#volkermxxxxxng1mfwef00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#volkermxxxxxng1mfwef00000] (initialized)
83213 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#volkermxxxxxng1mfwef00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#volkermxxxxxng1mfwef00000] (uninitialized)
83215 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxs8b7jkgf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxs8b7jkgf00000] (initialized)
83217 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxs8b7jkgf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxs8b7jkgf00000] (uninitialized)
83218 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#matthiasmxxxzp8dy3kf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#matthiasmxxxzp8dy3kf00000] (initialized)
83219 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#matthiasmxxxzp8dy3kf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#matthiasmxxxzp8dy3kf00000] (uninitialized)
83221 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxxi5wsoxkf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxxi5wsoxkf00000] (initialized)
83222 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxxi5wsoxkf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxxi5wsoxkf00000] (uninitialized)
83224 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxxt4cqcmke00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxxt4cqcmke00000] (initialized)
83225 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxxt4cqcmke00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxxt4cqcmke00000] (uninitialized)
83227 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#stephaniezxxk16hrvwd00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#stephaniezxxk16hrvwd00000] (initialized)
83228 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#stephaniezxxk16hrvwd00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#stephaniezxxk16hrvwd00000] (uninitialized)
83229 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxx71uq9ef00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxx71uq9ef00000] (initialized)
83230 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxx71uq9ef00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxx71uq9ef00000] (uninitialized)
83232 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klausaxxxxxx7kuzzrgf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klausaxxxxxx7kuzzrgf00000] (initialized)
83233 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klausaxxxxxx7kuzzrgf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klausaxxxxxx7kuzzrgf00000] (uninitialized)
83235 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxa63670ig00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxa63670ig00000] (initialized)
83236 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxa63670ig00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxa63670ig00000] (uninitialized)
83237 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxct3670ig00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxct3670ig00000] (initialized)
83239 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxct3670ig00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxct3670ig00000] (uninitialized)
83241 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx3a4670ig00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx3a4670ig00000] (initialized)
83242 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx3a4670ig00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx3a4670ig00000] (uninitialized)
83243 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx4a4670ig00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx4a4670ig00000] (initialized)
83244 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx4a4670ig00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx4a4670ig00000] (uninitialized)
83246 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx7h5670ig00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxx7h5670ig00000] (initialized)
83247 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx7h5670ig00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxx7h5670ig00000] (uninitialized)
83249 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxxyqqhunff00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxxyqqhunff00000] (initialized)
83250 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxxyqqhunff00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxxyqqhunff00000] (uninitialized)
83251 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#matthiasmxxx2vgaz8gf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#matthiasmxxx2vgaz8gf00000] (initialized)
83252 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#matthiasmxxx2vgaz8gf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#matthiasmxxx2vgaz8gf00000] (uninitialized)
83254 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klausaxxxxxx1iulmlhf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klausaxxxxxx1iulmlhf00000] (initialized)
83256 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klausaxxxxxx1iulmlhf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klausaxxxxxx1iulmlhf00000] (uninitialized)
83258 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#matthiasmxxxla56txaf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#matthiasmxxxla56txaf00000] (initialized)
83259 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#matthiasmxxxla56txaf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#matthiasmxxxla56txaf00000] (uninitialized)
83261 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#matthiasmxxx3d9fxjjf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#matthiasmxxx3d9fxjjf00000] (initialized)
83262 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#matthiasmxxx3d9fxjjf00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#matthiasmxxx3d9fxjjf00000] (uninitialized)
83265 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxav9sv6of00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxav9sv6of00000] (initialized)
83266 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxav9sv6of00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxav9sv6of00000] (uninitialized)
83268 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00500], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00500] (initialized)
83269 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00500], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00500] (uninitialized)
83271 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00600], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00600] (initialized)
83272 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00600], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00600] (uninitialized)
83274 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#matthiasmxxx47ji3p6f00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#matthiasmxxx47ji3p6f00000] (initialized)
83275 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#matthiasmxxx47ji3p6f00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#matthiasmxxx47ji3p6f00000] (uninitialized)
83277 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#dominiknxxxxjfqmz0ze00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#dominiknxxxxjfqmz0ze00000] (initialized)
83279 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#dominiknxxxxjfqmz0ze00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#dominiknxxxxjfqmz0ze00000] (uninitialized)
83280 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxhkksw12f00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxhkksw12f00000] (initialized)
83281 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxhkksw12f00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxhkksw12f00000] (uninitialized)
83283 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#volkermxxxxxlacflt4f00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#volkermxxxxxlacflt4f00000] (initialized)
83285 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#volkermxxxxxlacflt4f00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#volkermxxxxxlacflt4f00000] (uninitialized)
83287 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxbykxnt4f00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxbykxnt4f00000] (initialized)
83288 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxbykxnt4f00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxbykxnt4f00000] (uninitialized)
83290 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxx3yjrcc5f00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxx3yjrcc5f00000] (initialized)
83292 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxx3yjrcc5f00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxx3yjrcc5f00000] (uninitialized)
83293 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxvn60kjae00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxvn60kjae00000] (initialized)
83294 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxvn60kjae00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxvn60kjae00000] (uninitialized)
83296 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxvt4k5lae00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxvt4k5lae00000] (initialized)
83297 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxvt4k5lae00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxvt4k5lae00000] (uninitialized)
83298 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxjh8vgube00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxjh8vgube00000] (initialized)
83300 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxjh8vgube00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxjh8vgube00000] (uninitialized)
83302 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxewshlhnd00200], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxewshlhnd00200] (initialized)
83304 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxewshlhnd00200], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxewshlhnd00200] (uninitialized)
83305 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxbzktcwpe00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxbzktcwpe00000] (initialized)
83306 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxbzktcwpe00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxbzktcwpe00000] (uninitialized)
83308 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00100], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00100] (initialized)
83309 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00100], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#userxxxxxxxxixshlhnd00100] (uninitialized)
83311 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxx9ufj1kxe00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxx9ufj1kxe00000] (initialized)
83312 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxx9ufj1kxe00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxx9ufj1kxe00000] (uninitialized)
83315 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxx9rqs19re00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxx9rqs19re00000] (initialized)
83316 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxx9rqs19re00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxx9rqs19re00000] (uninitialized)
83317 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxx3azn7bue00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxx3azn7bue00000] (initialized)
83319 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxx3azn7bue00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxx3azn7bue00000] (uninitialized)
83320 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxxr2mckse00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#normanzxxxxxxr2mckse00000] (initialized)
83323 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxxr2mckse00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#normanzxxxxxxr2mckse00000] (uninitialized)
83325 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxx7ctl5kxe00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#klaushxxxxxx7ctl5kxe00000] (initialized)
83327 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxx7ctl5kxe00000], was: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.workingList#klaushxxxxxx7ctl5kxe00000] (uninitialized)
83328 [Gui4j-Worker 0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections  - Collection found: [de.bea.plato.domain.Mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterZeit#userxxxxxxxxewshlhnd00100], was:
```

Comment: Perhaps this can be the problem too.